# Converting an array of numbers in a Json to a SQL table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

**CONTEXT**

I have a table with a column that contains JSON data. The array size is not constant. The size can be as large as 999. However, the exact size can be figured out if needed (in this case it is 12).

```
CREATE TABLE TB_PRACTICE (
Id int Identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
JsonCol nvarchar(max))
```

Sample JSON in the "JsonCol" column

```
 [{"JsonId":85,"Values":[763,1356,1900,2419,2925,3420,3907,4389,4866,5338,5808,6274]}
 ,{"JsonId":86,"Values":[790,1391,1941,2465,2975,3474,3965,4450,4929,5405,5877,6346]}
 ,{"JsonId":87,"Values":[820,1429,1984,2514,3028,3531,4025,4514,4997,5475,5950,6422]}
 ,{"JsonId":88,"Values":[851,1469,2031,2566,3085,3592,4090,4582,5068,5550,6028,6502]}
 ,{"JsonId":89,"Values":[885,1512,2081,2622,3146,3657,4160,4655,5145,5630,6111,6589]}
 ,{"JsonId":90,"Values":[923,1560,2136,2683,3211,3728,4235,4734,5228,5716,6201,6682]}]
```

**REQUIREMENT**

I want to convert each JSON object to a result set as follows. Items in the array should be the column values of the result set.

| JsonId | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85 | 763 | 1356 | 1900 | 2419 | 2925 | 3420 | 3907 | 4389 | 4866 | 5338 | 5808 | 6274 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 90 | 923 | 1560 | 2136 | 2683 | 3211 | 3728 | 4235 | 4734 | 5228 | 5716 | 6201 | 6682 |

**ATTEMPTS**

Approach 1: Here I would have to iterate through each array location and dump the required data to a temp table and dynamically form the result set

```
Declare @i nvarchar(max)= '0';
Declare @comm nvarchar(max) =
 'SELECT Id,JsonId,[Values]          
  FROM TB_PRACTICE             
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(JsonCol, ''$''))             
  WITH (JsonId int ''$.JsonId'',           
  [Values] int ''$.Values['+@i+']'')           
  Where JsonCol not in ('''') '
 exec(@comm)
```

Approach 2: Here, I will get data row wise and not column wise

```
   SELECT j1.JsonId, j2.[Values]
FROM OPENJSON((select top 1 JsonCol from TB_PRACTICE), '$') WITH (
    JsonId int '$.JsonId',
    [Values] nvarchar(max) '$.Values'  AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[Values]) WITH (
    [Values] int '$'
) j2
```

**Question**
Is there a simple way to achieve the requirement or do I have to use one of the above approaches to get the desired result set?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL here? Could the number of values (in the array) change?

Comment: @Larnu Yes. It could change.

Comment: This sounds more like this is something that should be done in the presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: @Sampath, do you know the maximum possible count of items in the `$.Values` JSON array?

Comment: @Zhorov The count can be as large as 999. However, the exact size can be figured out if needed.

Comment: @Sampath, if you know the array length, a possible option is to define the schema: `SELECT * FROM TB_PRACTICE t CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JsonCol) WITH (JsonId int '$.JsonId', [1] int '$.Values[0]', ..., [100] int '$.Values[99]')`

Comment: So what do you want? 999 columns?? Seems excessive, perhaps you should consider a different method of presentation. Showing them row-wise seems more sensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamic statement is an option. The idea is to get all different indexes and build the `WITH` clause dynamically:

```
DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max)

-- Generate the schema
SELECT @stmt = (
   SELECT CONCAT(N', [', (ArrayId + 1), N'] int ''$.Values[', ArrayId , N']''')
   FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(int, j2.[key]) AS ArrayId
      FROM TB_PRACTICE t
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JsonCol) j1
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$.Values') j2
   ) t
   ORDER BY ArrayId
   FOR XML PATH('')
)  
-- Generate the final statement
SELECT @stmt = CONCAT(
   N'SELECT j.* ', 
   N'FROM TB_PRACTICE t ', 
   N'CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JsonCol) WITH (', 
   N'JsonId int ''$.JsonId''', 
   @stmt,
   N') j '
) 

-- Execute the statement
DECLARE @err int
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stmt
IF @err <> 0 PRINT 'Error'
```

Result:

| JsonId | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85 | 763 | 1356 | 1900 | 2419 | 2925 | 3420 | 3907 | 4389 | 4866 | 5338 | 5808 | 6274 |
| 86 | 790 | 1391 | 1941 | 2465 | 2975 | 3474 | 3965 | 4450 | 4929 | 5405 | 5877 | 6346 |
| 87 | 820 | 1429 | 1984 | 2514 | 3028 | 3531 | 4025 | 4514 | 4997 | 5475 | 5950 | 6422 |
| 88 | 851 | 1469 | 2031 | 2566 | 3085 | 3592 | 4090 | 4582 | 5068 | 5550 | 6028 | 6502 |
| 89 | 885 | 1512 | 2081 | 2622 | 3146 | 3657 | 4160 | 4655 | 5145 | 5630 | 6111 | 6589 |
| 90 | 923 | 1560 | 2136 | 2683 | 3211 | 3728 | 4235 | 4734 | 5228 | 5716 | 6201 | 6682 |

Comment: I used the above solution plus by joining a temp table having 2 column (HeaderName & ROW_NUMBER()), I was able to assign column name as well. `JOIN #temp tmp ON tmp.Row_Number = (ArrayId + 1)`. And change `SELECT CONCAT(N', [', (ArrayId + 1), N'] int ''$.Values[', ArrayId , N']''')` to `SELECT CONCAT(N', [', tmp.HeaderName , N'] int ''$.Values[', ArrayId , N']''')`